# Use multiple elements to trigger single onclick function

Tags: javascript, onclick

Right now this will work when I click "box1" but not "box2". I'd like to have a single tapBoxes variable that listens for a click on either box1 OR box2, and triggers the function. Any ideas?

```
var tapBoxes = document.getElementById("box1") || document.getElementById("box2"); 

tapBoxes.onclick = function() {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function first. Then assign it to all the buttons you want.

```
tapBoxesClick = function() {
 ...
 }

document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", tapBoxesClick, false);
document.getElementById("box2").addEventListener("click", tapBoxesClick, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your elements a class, lets say myBox, then use jquery to do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.myBox').click(function(){
     //do what you want with the clicked box

   })
})
```